# On Cauchy sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, metric-spaces

If $f:X\longrightarrow X$ is continuous (and injective) map on a complete metric space $(X,d)$ such that $\{fx_n\}$ is a Cauchy sequence, then can we conclude that $\{x_n\}$ is also a Cauchy sequence?

Here is my try: Suppose not, then for some $\varepsilon>0$, 
$$d(x_n,x_m)\geq\varepsilon$$
for all $n$ and $m$. But by the continuity of $f$ and $d$, we get
$$d(fx_n,fx_m)\geq \varepsilon^\prime=f(\varepsilon),$$
contradicting $\{fx_n\}$ is a Cauchy sequence.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Considering a proof by contradiction, it looked like an affirmative answer. But I am not so sure.

Comment: @markhaokip Add your attempt to the body of the question. This will prevent the question from getting closed.

Comment: Contradiction is often better done by considering specific example.  Consider for a moment $f:{\mathbb R}\rightarrow {\mathbb R}$ given by $f(x)=1/x$.  Is $\{1/n \mid n\in {\mathbb N} \}$ Cauchy?  How about its pre-image?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take the the the function defined piece wise where $f(x)=1/x$ from $x \in (1,+\infty)$ and a decreasing line in $(-\infty, 1]$ such that $f(1)=1$. This is a continuous injective function.  Now take the sequence $(1,2,3, \dots)$. It is not Cauchy, but its image is $(1,1/2,1/3,\dots)$, which is Cauchy.